# Complex numbers and circle group

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $U_{1}$ be the circle group on $\mathbb{C}^\times$

For my mathimatics study, I have to prove that there is an isomorphism

f: $U_{1}\times \mathbb{R}^+$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}^\times$

How do I prove this?

I was thinking of f(θ, r) = re^(2πiθ), since all elements on C are of the form re^θi, but maybe there is a much easier proof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explicitly state what you're considering the circle group?

Comment: Your idea is perfect and you'll see it's really not that hard to work it out in detail.